# Inconsistent Paging in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, paging

I am using ASP.NET CORE.

I found a paging tutorial online and the codes are pasted below. I tried it out on my website but there was a problem that I faced. I set the `pageSize` to 20 so that it will display 20 sets of data per page. However, the number of data that were displayed are inconsistent (eg. 11 lines of data in one page and 13 on the next)

1. How do I make it so that it will consistently show 20 sets of data per page?
2. What do I need to add so that the paging control contain the page number (1,2,3,4...) in between the existing "next" and "previous" page button?

```
namespace test
{
    public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

        public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            PageIndex = pageIndex;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

            this.AddRange(items);
        }

        public bool HasPreviousPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex > 1);
            }
        }

        public bool HasNextPage
        {
            get
            {
                return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
            var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
            return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(
    string sortOrder,
    string currentFilter,
    string searchString,
    int? pageNumber)
{
    ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
    ViewData["NameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
    ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

    var students = from s in _context.Students
                   select s;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                               || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
    }
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "name_desc":
            students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
            break;
        case "Date":
            students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
            break;
        case "date_desc":
            students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
            break;
        default:
            students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
            break;
    }

    int pageSize = 20;
    return View(await PaginatedList<Student>.CreateAsync(students.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

View Page:

```
@model PaginatedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <p>
            Find by name: <input type="text" name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" />
            <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" /> |
            <a asp-action="Index">Back to Full List</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["NameSortParm"]" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]">Last Name</a>
            </th>
            <th>
                First Name
            </th>
            <th>
                <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["DateSortParm"]" asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]">Enrollment Date</a>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMidName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EnrollmentDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@{
    var prevDisabled = !Model.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
    var nextDisabled = !Model.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
}

<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex - 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
    Previous
</a>
<a asp-action="Index"
   asp-route-sortOrder="@ViewData["CurrentSort"]"
   asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.PageIndex + 1)"
   asp-route-currentFilter="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]"
   class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
    Next
</a>
```

Comment: Since you already know `pageNumber` and `pageSize` in you controller from which you pass `List<>` then you could use `linq` in that combination like `List<>().Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)` and inside view you will get only list of 20 items so do not need any further validation

Comment: To check if the pagination is working. Don't do some search for now just load all the data. Then try to do next or previous.

Comment: I would advice you to use NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6. A typical site contains several tables, NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6 will help keeping your codebase smaller. If you are forced to be IE11-compliant, use version 5.1.2.

Comment: @AleksaRistic How will that look like

Comment: @tontonsevilla I tried it, but the number of data per page is still inconsistent

Comment: @RoarS. Do you have a recommended website for me to follow?

Comment: @addsw: Yes, https://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/ Enjoy :-)

Comment: @RoarS. Hi, I followed the website and changed accordingly. However, nothing is showing on my website.

Comment: @addsw: Except for that you'll need to copy a few things into your project, it should be quite easy to use, and it is well documented. I recommend using 30 minutes on figuring out whats wrong. If unsuccessful, leave it.

Comment: @addsw: There is one issue with lint and latest version, go for version 5.1.2 as a first-time user. Let's keep in touch, and I'll show you how to fix lint for latest version when you are up-and-running.

Comment: @RoarS. where can i find this "Windows: %UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6\{version}\content\Views\". I can't seem to find my %UserProfile% folder

Comment: On my Windows-machine, it is here: C:\Users\roars\.nuget\packages\nonfactors.grid.mvc6\5.1.2\content\Views